# Process is giving error result , and not continuing but able finish the process get the output

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, async-await, task

I have a process created for generating web API in Dotnet core as shown below which will return a result after completion:

```
public static async Task<ProcessResult> RunProcessAsync(string command, string arguments, int timeout)
                 {
                    var result = new ProcessResult();
                    
                    process.StartInfo.FileName = "dotnet";
                    process.StartInfo.Arguments = " new webapi -n dotnet45.Api -o /tmp/CodeGenOutput/dotnet4520220523110059849";
                    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
                    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
                    process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                    
                    result.Command = command;
                    result.Arguments = arguments;

                var outputBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            var outputCloseEvent = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

            process.OutputDataReceived += (s, e) =>
            {
                // The output stream has been closed i.e. the process has terminated
                if (e.Data == null)
                {
                    outputCloseEvent.SetResult(true);
                }
                else
                {
                    outputBuilder.AppendLine(e.Data);
                }
            };

            var errorBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            var errorCloseEvent = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

                       process.ErrorDataReceived += (s, e) =>
            {
                // The error stream has been closed i.e. the process has terminated
                if (e.Data == null)
                {
                    errorCloseEvent.SetResult(true);
                }
                else
                {
                    errorBuilder.AppendLine(e.Data);
                }
            };
                process.Start();

                   // Reads the output stream first and then waits because deadlocks are possible
                    process.BeginOutputReadLine();
                    process.BeginErrorReadLine();

                    // Creates task to wait for process exit using timeout
                      timeout = 3000;
                    var waitForExit = WaitForExitAsync(process, timeout);

                    // Create task to wait for process exit and closing all output streams
                    var processTask = Task.WhenAll(waitForExit, outputCloseEvent.Task, errorCloseEvent.Task);

                    // Waits process completion and then checks it was not completed by timeout
                    if (await Task.WhenAny(Task.Delay(timeout), processTask) == processTask && waitForExit.Result)
                    {
                        result.Completed = true;
                        result.ExitCode = process.ExitCode;

                        // Adds process output if it was completed with error
                        if (process.ExitCode != 0)
                        {
                            result.Output = $"{outputBuilder}{errorBuilder}";
                        }
                    }
                    
                return result;
                }
```

The return value of above function (result variable) is shown below which is an error:

```
 {
                             "ExitCode": null,
                             "Output": null,
                             "Error": null,
                             "Command": "dotnet",
                             "Arguments": " new webapi -n dotnet45.Api -o /tmp/CodeGenOutput/dotnet4520220523110059849",
                             "Completed": false,
                             "OutputBuilder": null,
                             "ErrorBuilder": null
                          }
```

Here is the implementation of waitforexitasync

```
private static Task<bool> WaitForExitAsync(Process process, int timeout)
    {
        return Task.Run(() => process.WaitForExit(timeout));
    }
```

But as I know, even though there is an error returned, the intended purpose of creation of Dotnet webapi is completed by the above method and I am able to see the generated web API in the output folder /tmp/CodeGenOutput/dotnet4520220523110059849.

1. My first issue is why there is null output in the result?
2. The second issue is why the program is not continuing, since there
   is an error, it just breaks there, but I need to continue either
   fixing this null error or without fixing this error.

Please share some lights on this!

Comment: Where is the code that logs the error ("Generation of Server Code webapi Errored")? How is it determining that this was an error? How is `WaitForExit` implemented, and what would make its `Result` true or false?

Comment: just take "return result;"  line, return variable have error log which i posted there, i am not posting the entire line because error log is generated through series of layers

Comment: updated waitforexit defenition above!

Comment: Updated few more lines for better understanding

Comment: It seems like the `Task.Delay(timeout)` must be completing before  `processTask`.

Comment: i increased from 3000 to 10000 , but still error is there

Comment: What is the reason for the separate delay, rather than checking the result of the `WaitForExit` task?

Comment: Can you do a little more work to narrow down the problem? What's the value in `errorBuilder` and `outputBuilder` just before you return? What are the states of each of the `Tasks`? What happens if you change the process and arguments to do something more simple?

Comment: when change the command (creating web api)program is executing successfully, Also this error is only happening in server and not in localhost

Comment: What is the reason for the separate delay,  i really dont know why they put a delay as there is already waitforexit. Can i remove this?